# what type of data can class type store?

Tags: java

Primitive type  `int x =1;` stores primitive data, `String y ="jk" ;` refers to string object, what does `class Dog { Dog d; }`type data store? Or we instantiate Dog class in the data filed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable of a class type – like a String – stores objects of its class differently from how variables of primitive types – like int or char – store their values. Every variable, whether it’s of a primitive type or of a class type, is implemented as a location in computer memory. For a variable of a primitive type, the value of the variable is stored in the memory location assigned to the variable. So, if an integer variable is declared as `int x = 3,` then when we look at the memory location of “x”, there will be a “3” stored there just as expected.

However, a variable of a class type only stores the memory address of where the object is located – not the values inside the object. So, if we have a class called `Dog`, when we create an object like this: `Dog dog`, then when we look at `dog` in memory, we will see that it does not store any of the variables that belong to that object in memory. Instead, the variable `dog` just stores an address of another place in memory where all the details of `dog` reside. This means that the object named by the variable is stored in some other location in memory and the variable contains only the memory address of where the object is stored. This memory address is called a reference to the object.

Answer (score 5):

As you said for string :

d refer to a Dog object

;)

I am not sure to understand your question but more seriously imagine a graph structure You need node that point to other node so The class node can be write like your dog class:

```
class Node {
       Node nextNode1;
 }
```

for example.

In fact nextNode1 or d or y store the same thing a pointer to the structure that represent the object. and this structure contain for example your string "jk" or the dog (it's name, age, gender....) this structure can also contain only a self-referencing pointer

And maybe you are talking about the [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type that is the object used to represent a java class

Answer (score 2):

Class type stores objects of it's classes.When you say `Class object = new Class()`, on the right hand side you're assigning a new object to the class type.Although the object only refers to the memory location.

Answer (score 1):

A class will hold anything you define for it.

```
public class IHoldAString
{
    public String s ;
}

public class IHoldTwoStringsAndAnInteger
{
    public String sFoo, sBar ;
    public int z ;
}
```

Class instances in Java are *objects* that allow you to store and manipulate structured data. It sounds like you're only beginning to learn about Java and object-oriented programming in general, so... Good luck! Do some reading, and enjoy.